# How to use cellTemplate in calendarOptions of devextreme react DateBox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devextreme, devextreme-react

It appears that the [demo](https://js.devexpress.com/React/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Calendar/Overview/MaterialBlueLight/) on `devextreme-react` for `cellTemplate` is just another use of `cellRender`.

Although it was mentioned that both `cellComponent` and `cellRender` are just:

> An alias for the cellTemplate property specified in React.

It does not work when I tried to customize the cells in the calendar for `DateBox` (for example, as I want to change the `color` of weekends to `red`):

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import DateBox from 'devextreme-react/date-box';
import moment from 'moment';

const CustomDateBox = () => {
  const isWeekend = (date) => [0, 6].includes(moment(date).day());

  const renderCell = (cellData) => (
    <div style={{ color: isWeekend(cellData.date) ? 'red' : 'inherit' }}>
      {cellData.text}
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <DateBox
      labelMode="hidden"
      openOnFieldClick={true}
      hoverStateEnabled={false}
      calendarOptions={{
        cellTemplate: renderCell
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomDateBox;
```

And it returns a plank calendar with no context in it, even though the "cells" are still clickable.

[image: Edit devextreme-react-datebox-with-celltemplate]